# Hide entire row if the same value on col A and B

Tags: excel, vba

If the same value on col A and B in the same row like 5 5 or 22 22
then I'd like to hide entire row or unfilter those rows.

```
sub myExample
    dim filter_Z as range, rowW as range, COLA as range, COLB as range

    dim last_row as long

    Set filter_Z = Sheets(1).Range("A1" & last_row)

    '
    For Each rowW In filter_Z.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    '
    COLA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheets1").Range("A" & rowW.Row).Value
    COLB = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheets1").").Range("B" & rowW.Row).Value

    If COLA=COLB Then rowW.EntireRow.Hidden = True

     Next rowW
end sub
```

Comment: You have a very obvious typo in your COLB line. Correct that for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should at least point you in the correct direction:

```
Option Explicit
Sub hideRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rw As Range
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    For Each rw In sh.Rows
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value And sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value Then
            rw.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next rw

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```